# Fetch Objects unexpectedly executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fetch

I'm working with node.  I have an api setup as a netlify serverless function , so that I can run a number of processes in parallel.

As part of this I want so create an array of unexecuted fetch object promises, which I can then execute in paralell using something like:

```
const responses = await Promise.allSettled(promiseArray);
```

So far I have:

```
for (let i = 0; i < groupedRecords.length; i++) {
  const groupedRecord = groupedRecords[i];
  const fetchObjects = await createFetchObjectArray(groupedRecord);

}

async function createFetchObjectArray(records) {


  const fetchURL = (obj) => fetch('http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/meta1', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(obj),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  });

 let outputArray = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < (records.length); i++) {
    const record = await records.pop();
    const obj = { "_id": record._id };
    const fetchObj = fetchURL(obj);
    outputArray.push(fetchObj);

  }

  return outputArray;

}
```

I was hoping to get an array of promises into 'fetchObjects', however they appear to be trying to execute. I'm seeing:

```
FetchError: request to http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/meta1 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
```

how to I keep the fetch objects from executing?

Comment: What is the data structure `groupedRecords`?

Comment: `await records.pop()` doesn't really make sense. What `records` are you passing in?

Comment: "*which I can then execute in paralell using something like `Promise.allSettled`*" - you are mistaken about how promises work. You cannot "execute" them, they're not functions. All you can do is to wait for them. And that's also what `Promise.allSettled` does: it creates a new promise that waits for all of the input promises to settle. It is fundamentally impossible to "*keep fetch objects from executing*" - calling `fetch()` **does execute** the function, it returns a promise that lets you wait for the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `fetchURL` will execute it immediately. `await` or `Promise.allSettled` are not mechanisms to *start* asynchronous operations, they are mechanisms to wait for an operation that has already kicked off.

If you want to build an array of functions and not call them immediately, instead of:

```
const fetchObj = fetchURL(obj);
outputArray.push(fetchObj);
```

You probably just want:

```
outputArray.push(() => fetchURL(obj));
```

If you later on want to use `Promise.allSettled`, you could do this as such:

```
Promise.allSettled(outputArray.map(foo => foo());
```

Here's a cleaned up version of your code that also fixes more bugs:

```js
for(const groupedRecord of groupedRecords) {
  const fetchObjects = createFetchObjectArray(groupedRecord);
  // Assuming you're doing something with fetchObjects after?
}

function fetchURL(obj) {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/meta1', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(obj),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  });
}

function createFetchObjectArray(records) {

  return records.map(record => {
    const obj = { "_id": record._id };
    return () => fetchURL(obj);
  });

}
```

Comment: Thank you - As a teaching point for me, I notice that a lot of your code is synchronous , whereas I am using more asynchronous functions - Should I try to structure more of my code as syncronous?

Comment: @user1592380 there _are_ asynchronous operations here too, but as long as you don't have to `await` anything, you also shouldn't mark functions as `async`. I didn't deliberately avoid `await` or `async`, it just wasn't needed here.

Comment: I'm never sure what operations  require async/await in js. In general terms I know that I/O operations need this. Any pointers on how to be sure?

Comment: @user1592380 you only need await if something returns a promise. If it didn't return a promise, `await` does nothing.

Comment: So does adding the async keyword before a function result in a a returned promise?

Comment: @user1592380 yes but it only makes sense to mark a function as async if you use `await` in the function.